# How to understand a single packet embedded with multiple requests?

Tags: http, attacks, ddos

When I read [Multi VERB Single Request](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5548bab5e4b08ecb6652391c/t/554923d6e4b03d6d83ac7c5e/1430856662717/RioRey_Taxonomy_DDoS_Attacks_2.6_2015-1.pdf):

> This Attack is also a variation of the Excessive Verb Attack
> strategy. The attacking BOT creates multiple HTTP requests, not by issuing them one after
> another during a single HTTP session, but by forming a single packet embedded with multiple
> requests.

How to understand the `a single packet embedded with multiple requests`?

is it mean one HTTP request packet have multiple HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

> .. is it mean one HTTP request packet have multiple HTTP requests?

There is no such thing as a "HTTP request packet". This is about a  single TCP packet containing a payload and this payload consisting of multiple HTTP requests. Usually HTTP is working by sending a request and waiting for the response but with HTTP pipelining it is also possible to send multiple requests at once (no matter if within a single TCP packet or using multiple TCP packets) and then reading all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about HTTP pipelining, that basically is have more than one method on the request. This means that you can have, for example 3 GET operations, on the same request. Check [HTTP Pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) for further information.